# How can I clean up the traces left by a trial antivirus program I uninstalled?

Tags: files

Let's say I installed an antivirus program for a trial period. Then I did not like it and uninstalled it. But I am definitely sure that it leaves some files, traces etc. behind. So how can I clean my Ubuntu 12.04 OS that is like did not installed the trial program at all?

Comment: Did you install it with `apt-get` or `dpkg`?

Comment: are you looking for the Windows' AppData folder equivalent for Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

Try running

```
sudo apt-get clean

sudo apt-get autoremove
```

from terminal

These will clear caches and remove programs and files that aren't used/needed anymore.

To remove personal information regarding the application, you would need to check in your /home

Run nautilus and enable hidden folders

```
Ctrl +h
```